# Optimizing Code for Data Dictionary (python function tips)

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, deep-learning, pickle

I am an extremely amateur coder, who is looking to optimize code for time purposes. I have included my code below.

*I realize this is bad/inefficient code*

These eleven `mod_files` (eg. OOK_IQ) are incredibly large ~200 MB a piece (in text file format, stupid I know), so iterating line by line there are approximately 40 million lines per file. Each with 2 elements with a comma as a delimiter. So ultimately I want to create a `[2, 40 M]` matrix for each modulation file.

Example `mod_file`:

```
0.00234, -0.20123  
0.01643, -0.11200   
etc...
```

I would then want to subdivide as you can see with the succeeding for loops.

```
import numpy as np
import pickle
import time

modulations = ['OOK', '4ASK', '8ASK', 'BPSK', 'QPSK', '8PSK', '16PSK', '32PSK', '16APSK', '32APSK', '64APSK', '128APSK', '16QAM', '32QAM', '64QAM', '128QAM', '256QAM']

mod_files = [j + '_IQ' for j in modulations]

peter_piper = {}; set_count = 0; mod_count = 0;

for modtype in modulations:
    for mod_file in mod_files:
        mod_count+=1;
        print("We are in modulation loop: ", + mod_count);        
        with open(mod_file, 'r') as f:
            data = [] 

            track = 0
            print("Splitting lines . . .")
            time1 = time.time();
            for row_num, line in enumerate(f):                
                values = line.strip().split('\n')                
                for numbers in values:        
                    inphase, quad = numbers.strip().split(',')
                    if track == 0:                    
                        data = np.asarray([[float(inphase)],[float(quad)]])                    
                    else:
                        data= np.append(data, [[float(inphase)],[float(quad)]],axis=1)                
                track += 1
            print("Track number: ", + track);         
            time2 = time.time(); print("File read time: ", + (time2-time1))        
            data.astype(np.float32)            
            subarrays = []
            print("Splitting into subarrays ...");            
            subarrays = np.array_split(data, 39000, axis=1) # 1500 examples per SNR
            array_count = 0;     
            for i in range(1500):            
                for snr in range(-20, 32, 2):
                    t1 = time.time();                    
                    which_array = []                    
                    which_array = subarrays[array_count]
                    which_array[abs(which_array) > 2] = 0;
                    peter_piper[(modtype, str(snr))] = which_array
                    array_count += 1; t2 = time.time();             
                    print("*** SNR Loop Time: ", + (t2-t1));
                #basic_data = array(data)'''
            f.close()
            print(subarrays[0], subarrays[0].shape)
            set_count+=1
            print("*****The array count is, " + set_count + "of 17 modulations")
pickle.dump(peter_piper, open("2018_IQ_dataset_v1","wb"))
```

I'm sure some of you are thinking that this will be an extremely time consuming program. And so far simply creating the first of 17 initial matrices is taking over an hour. I anticipate just this part taking a day.

I am desperate to find an overall time solution here.

**Would saving the initial data "`mod_files`" in binary or some other format improve this project? Or is the sheer amount of data too large?**

Any efficiency tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The data size isn't the problem, its just that given the size, you have to be way more careful about the manipulations you do. E.g. printing in a loop is probably not a good call.

Comment: Appending to numpy arrays is very inefficient. They do not do well when changing in size. You might be better building lists and then converting to an array at the end. Appending to lists is faster. Or, if you know the final length, instantiate the array as empty and assign values by index.

Comment: I don't know how to mark your answer as the best @roganjosh, but it works like a champ with lists (rather than np.arrays) now!

Comment: I'm curious of the speed upgrade? You can't accept my answer, I just made a comment :) there may be other things you can do, that's the first I noticed.

Comment: Its a very large upgrade in speed. It was taking about 4 hours to do a loop that took about 24 seconds. I guess its because it looped about 39M times, so whatever it was got multiplied